# TCP - Identity of timed out client

Tags: tcp, timeout, client

I want to know the identity of the timed out client ?
how ?

if the function that will receive data like this ..How can I know the client ID ?

your help will be greatly appreciated

Thank you :)

```
   DWORD WINAPI Server::ClientThread(LPVOID lpParam)

    {


             char receivedData[BUFFER_SIZE];
             ThreadData  myThreadData = *(ThreadData*)lpParam;
             while (1)
             {
                 int returnValue;
                 // Perform a blocking recv() call
                 returnValue = recv(myThreadData.clientSocket, receivedData, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

                 if (returnValue == 0)
                     break;
                 else if (returnValue == SOCKET_ERROR)
                 {
                     cout << "recv() failed - Error Code : " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     receivedData[returnValue] = '\0';
                     cout << "I am the server and received " << receivedData << endl;
                     UnderstandComingMessage(receivedData, myThreadData);
                 }



             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by 'identity', but you can get the peer IP address and port by calling `getpeername()` on the socket.